# Applet won't run off of server

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, publish

I have created a java game in the form of a java applet and I'm now trying to publish the applet to facebook. To do this I put my game on a webserver for free by making an account with Zymic. My problem is that the game doesn't run how its supposed to run from the server. The game starts up creates the player and some of the background then runs through a few iterations of the game loop then shuts down. I am almost 100% sure I have all of the files on the web server because I basically just copied the entire root directory folder onto the web server (All my applet's files are in one file on my computer). The applet runs completely fine from my computer though and if it makes any difference I used Eclipse to write and test the applet.

Comment: Can you get a stack trace from it somehow?

Comment: Sadly no. Not from the server. There may be a way though but I don't know how

Comment: Is this applet running in a web browser, or is it running remotely on the server and serving connections to some local component?

Comment: It runs on a web browser. If you would like to see what it's doing you can see it at: missokantorapp.zxq.net/index.htm It doesn't run like that from eclipse though. It works perfectly

Comment: If it's running in a web browser can't you just wrap the entire main loop in a try/catch and messagebox the exception when it gets thrown  Also, on windows, you should be able to see the java console.  There's an icon in the tray menu for it somewhere.

Comment: I'm on a mac and also on vacation so I wont be able to use my pc. But let me try the exception.

Comment: It didn't display a message box I put javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.toString()) for the catch code but it didn't throw a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the Java Console in line with the instructions below:

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

When your Applet runs it is throwing various security exceptions. Applets run in a sandbox and are restricted to what they can do by default: for example an unsigned Applet cannot connect to a remote server other than from which it was downloaded.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

From the console stacktrace, it looks like you may be trying to load an image from some remote URL.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.SecurityException
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.checkSecurity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.imageComplete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.errorConsumer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.errorAllConsumers(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.badDecoder(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: +1  If more applet developers could find the console, it would result in far fewer applet questions to answer.

Comment: I'm loading the image from the same file on the server as all of the source code. How do I fix this so it works?

Comment: Bundle the images in the Jar and read from there. You can use getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pathFromRootOfJar/image.png");